# Remove a non-clickable zone in the Bing Maps API

Tags: api, razor, bing-maps

I'm really not sure how I did this but I have a 'dead zone' of around 20px at the top of the Bing Map I inserted into a web page using the Bing Map API v7.

The zone displays everything fine but when I move the cursor up there it changes from a finger to a pointer and won't invoke the navigation bar options (like zoom) until I carefully select the very bottom of the nav bar just under this dead zone.

Where would I go looking to find out how to remove this 'dead zone'??

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure on this one. Can you provide a URL to a page that does this or sample code that reproduces it. Have you specified a CSS position on the map?